# Tokenizing hashtags in Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, analyzer

I am using Lucene.Net (version 2.9). I would like to preserve tweet post '@name' or '#Note'.

Using the Lucene AnalyzerViewer tool (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lucene_analysis.aspx?msg=3326095#xx3326095xx) to review tokens produced by different analyzer.

For example, tokens produced below from this text: "#Note: Excercise, to live longer."

- Whitespace Analyzer: [#Note:]   [Excercise,]   [to]   [live]   [longer.]
- Standard Analyzer: [note]   [excercise]   [live]   [longer]
- Simple Analyzer: [note]   [excercise]   [to]   [live]   [longer]

'Whitespace Analyzer' preserve the hash tags. I created a custom analyzer, which uses WhitespaceTokenizer and lower case.

Custom Analyzer code...

```
public class CustomAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, System.IO.TextReader reader)
    {
        TokenStream result = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);

        // Makes sure everything is lower case
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);

        //Return the built token stream.)
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, the custom analyzer leaves punctuations. Tokens produced by the custom analyzer: [#note:]   [excercise,]   [to]   [live]   [longer.]

Any suggestions to use a filter where '#', '@' tags preserve and punctuations removed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the java version of lucene there is a PatternAnalyzer, that lets you specify a pattern that will be used to split the tokens.

Documentation: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_4/api/contrib-memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/PatternAnalyzer.html

You could watch out for a .net version of this analyzer or port it your own.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Will keep an eye on the .Net port of the PatternAnalyzer.

In the meantime, we are thinking a workaround approach of extract tweet post (i.e. '@name', '#Note', etc) and store in a separate Lucene field and use Whitespace Analyzer.

Comment: You're welcome! I would suggest you write your own port to .net if it does not yet exist. It would only be a few lines of code ;)